# Can someone please explain about the functionality of "torch.bernoulli"?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a question about `torch.bernoulli`. According to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.bernoulli.html):

> Draws binary random numbers (0 or 1) from a Bernoulli distribution. The input tensor should be a tensor containing probabilities to be used for drawing the binary random number. Hence, all values in input have to be in the range:
> 0 ≤ input i ≤ 1. The i-th element of the output tensor will draw a value 1 according to i-th probability value given in input.

I don't quite get it. For example, if we have `torch.bernoulli([0.599, 0.0846, 0.0179, 0.0742, 0.0742])`, once it returns `tensor([1., 0., 0., 0., 0.])`. Another time it returns `tensor([0., 0., 0., 1., 0.])`. I don't understand why it behaves like that. The documentation states "...for drawing the binary **random** number...". But the whole proccess is vague to me. Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simplify your example to the input tensor `[0.60, 0.07, 0.12]`.  Now, on any given draw, there is a ...

```
60% chance that element 1 will be 1
 7% chance that element 2 will be 1
12% chance that element 3 will be 1
... and any elements that aren't 1 are 0.
```

These events are independent.  For instance, there is a chance of `0.60 * 0.07 * 0.12` that all three elements will be 1.  There is a `0.40 * 0.93 * 0.88` chance that all three will be 0.

Does that help clear it up?

Comment: Helpful explanation! Thank you very much.